# How to iterate over all elements of a 2D matrix using only one loop using python

Tags: python, numpy, loops

I know you can iterate over a 2d matrix using two indexes like this:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.zeros((10,10))

for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(0,10):
        if (i==j):
            A[i,j] = 4
```

Is there a way of doing this using only one for loop or using slices?

EDIT:

I also need to take into account of when i =/ j, for example:

```
A = np.zeros((10,10))

for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(0,10):
        if (i==j):
            A[i,j] = 1
        if (i+1 ==j):
            A[i,j] = 2
        if (i-1==j):
            A[i,j] = 3
```

Comment: you can use zip

Comment: Iterating through a numpy array is generally not a good practice. Can you explain more what you want to achieve here ?

Comment: You are only using where i and j are equal. so why not use one for loop?

Comment: @Psidom I need to rewrite the code so that it only uses 1 loop instead of two nested loops

Comment: Why one loop?  What's wrong with the 2?

Answer (score 1):

You can always collapse multiple loops into one by calculating the components each iteration with the modulo operator like so:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.zeros((10,10))

for x in range(100):
    i = math.floor(x/10)
    j = x % 10
    if (i==j):
        A[i,j] = 1
    if (i+1 ==j):
        A[i,j] = 2
    if (i-1==j):
        A[i,j] = 3
```

With only `i==j` it could be even simpler:

```
for i in range(10):
    A[i,i] = 4
```

Comment: One loop over 100 elements is just as slow as two loops over 10 and 10 - it's still visiting each element of `A` one by one.

Comment: @hpaulj This is correkt. But I did not claim that it was. OP just asked to do it in a single loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [129]: A = np.zeros((10,10), int)
     ...: for i in range(0,10):
     ...:     for j in range(0,10):
     ...:         if (i==j):
     ...:             A[i,j] = 1
     ...:         if (i+1 ==j):
     ...:             A[i,j] = 2
     ...:         if (i-1==j):
     ...:             A[i,j] = 3
     ...:
```

You should have shown the resulting `A`:

```
In [130]: A
Out[130]: 
array([[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1]])
```

So you have set 3 diagonals:

```
In [131]: A[np.arange(10),np.arange(10)]
Out[131]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
In [132]: A[np.arange(9),np.arange(1,10)]
Out[132]: array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
In [133]: A[np.arange(1,10),np.arange(9)]
Out[133]: array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
```

The key to eliminating loops in `numpy` is to get a big picture of the task, rather than focusing on the iterative steps.

There are various tools for making a diagonal array.  One is `np.diag`, which can be used thus:

```
In [139]: np.diag(np.ones(10,int),0)+
          np.diag(np.ones(9,int)*2,1)+
          np.diag(np.ones(9,int)*3,-1)
Out[139]: 
array([[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1]])
```

Or adapting [131] etc

```
In [140]: A = np.zeros((10,10), int)
     ...: A[np.arange(10),np.arange(10)]=1
     ...: A[np.arange(9),np.arange(1,10)]=2
     ...: A[np.arange(1,10),np.arange(9)]=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your only executing code when `i == j`, you can just use:

```py
for i in range(0,10):
    A[i,i] = 4
```