# Multigrid Poisson Solver

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, differential-equations

I am trying to make my own CFD solver and one of the most computationally expensive parts is solving for the pressure term. One way to solve Poisson differential equations faster is by using a [multigrid method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigrid_method). The basic recursive algorithm for this is:

```
function phi = V_Cycle(phi,f,h)
    % Recursive V-Cycle Multigrid for solving the Poisson equation (\nabla^2 phi = f) on a uniform grid of spacing h

    % Pre-Smoothing
    phi = smoothing(phi,f,h);
    
    % Compute Residual Errors
    r = residual(phi,f,h);
    
    % Restriction
    rhs = restriction(r);

    eps = zeros(size(rhs));

    % stop recursion at smallest grid size, otherwise continue recursion
    if smallest_grid_size_is_achieved
            eps = smoothing(eps,rhs,2*h);
    else        
            eps = V_Cycle(eps,rhs,2*h);        
    end
    
    % Prolongation and Correction
    phi = phi + prolongation(eps);
    
    % Post-Smoothing
    phi = smoothing(phi,f,h);    
end
```

[I've attempted to implement this algorithm myself](https://github.com/mcleantom/CFDPython/blob/master/Fluid%20Dynamics/Multigrid%20Methods/Chapter%201/2D%20Poisson%20Solver.py) (also at the end of this question) however it is very slow and doesn't give good results so evidently it is doing something wrong. I've been trying to find why for too long and I think it's just worthwhile seeing if anyone can help me.

If I use a grid size of 2^5 by 2^5 points, then it can solve it and give reasonable results. However, as soon as I go above this it takes exponentially longer to solve and basically get stuck at some level of inaccuracy, no matter how many V-Loops are performed. at 2^7 by 2^7 points, the code takes way too long to be useful.

I think my main issue is that my implementation of a jacobian iteration is using linear algebra to calculate the update at each step. This should, in general, be fast however, the update matrix A is an n*m sized matrix, and calculating the dot product of a 2^7 * 2^7 sized matrix is expensive. As most of the cells are just zeros, should I calculate the result using a different method?

if anyone has any experience in multigrid methods, I would appreciate any advice!

Thanks

my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Dec 29 16:24:16 2020

@author: mclea
"""

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from matplotlib import cm


def restrict(A):
    """
    Creates a new grid of points which is half the size of the original
    grid in each dimension.
    """
    n = A.shape[0]
    m = A.shape[1]
    new_n = int((n-2)/2+2)
    new_m = int((m-2)/2+2)
    new_array = np.zeros((new_n, new_m))
    for i in range(1, new_n-1):
        for j in range(1, new_m-1):
            ii = int((i-1)*2)+1
            jj = int((j-1)*2)+1
            # print(i, j, ii, jj)
            new_array[i,j] = np.average(A[ii:ii+2, jj:jj+2])
    new_array = set_BC(new_array)
    return new_array


def interpolate_array(A):
    """
    Creates a grid of points which is double the size of the original
    grid in each dimension. Uses linear interpolation between grid points.
    """
    n = A.shape[0]
    m = A.shape[1]
    new_n = int((n-2)*2 + 2)
    new_m = int((m-2)*2 + 2)
    new_array = np.zeros((new_n, new_m))
    i = (np.indices(A.shape)[0]/(A.shape[0]-1)).flatten()
    j = (np.indices(A.shape)[1]/(A.shape[1]-1)).flatten()

    A = A.flatten()
    new_i = np.linspace(0, 1, new_n)
    new_j = np.linspace(0, 1, new_m)
    new_ii, new_jj = np.meshgrid(new_i, new_j)
    new_array = griddata((i, j), A, (new_jj, new_ii), method="linear")
    return new_array


def adjacency_matrix(rows, cols):
    """
    Creates the adjacency matrix for an n by m shaped grid
    """
    n = rows*cols
    M = np.zeros((n,n))
    for r in range(rows):
        for c in range(cols):
            i = r*cols + c
            # Two inner diagonals
            if c > 0: M[i-1,i] = M[i,i-1] = 1
            # Two outer diagonals
            if r > 0: M[i-cols,i] = M[i,i-cols] = 1
    return M


def create_differences_matrix(rows, cols):
    """
    Creates the central differences matrix A for an n by m shaped grid
    """
    n = rows*cols
    M = np.zeros((n,n))
    for r in range(rows):
        for c in range(cols):
            i = r*cols + c
            # Two inner diagonals
            if c > 0: M[i-1,i] = M[i,i-1] = -1
            # Two outer diagonals
            if r > 0: M[i-cols,i] = M[i,i-cols] = -1
    np.fill_diagonal(M, 4)
    return M


def set_BC(A):
    """
    Sets the boundary conditions of the field
    """
    A[:, 0] = A[:, 1]
    A[:, -1] = A[:, -2]
    A[0, :] = A[1, :]
    A[-1, :] = A[-2, :]
    return A


def create_A(n,m):
    """
    Creates all the components required for the jacobian update function
    for an n by m shaped grid
    """
    LaddU = adjacency_matrix(n,m)
    A = create_differences_matrix(n,m)
    invD = np.zeros((n*m, n*m))
    np.fill_diagonal(invD, 1/4)
    return A, LaddU, invD


def calc_RJ(rows, cols):
    """
    Calculates the jacobian update matrix Rj for an n by m shaped grid
    """
    n = int(rows*cols)
    M = np.zeros((n,n))
    for r in range(rows):
        for c in range(cols):
            i = r*cols + c
            # Two inner diagonals
            if c > 0: M[i-1,i] = M[i,i-1] = 0.25
            # Two outer diagonals
            if r > 0: M[i-cols,i] = M[i,i-cols] = 0.25

    return M


def jacobi_update(v, f, nsteps=1, max_err=1e-3):
    """
    Uses a jacobian update matrix to solve nabla(v) = f
    """
    
    f_inner = f[1:-1, 1:-1].flatten()
    n = v.shape[0]
    m = v.shape[1]
    A, LaddU, invD = create_A(n-2, m-2)
    Rj = calc_RJ(n-2,m-2)

    update=True
    step = 0
    while update:
        v_old = v.copy()
        step += 1
        vt = v_old[1:-1, 1:-1].flatten()
        vt = np.dot(Rj, vt) + np.dot(invD, f_inner)
        v[1:-1, 1:-1] = vt.reshape((n-2),(m-2))
        err = v - v_old
        if step == nsteps or np.abs(err).max()<max_err:
            update=False
    
    return v, (step, np.abs(err).max())


def MGV(f, v):
    """
    Solves for nabla(v) = f using a multigrid method
    """
    # global  A, r
    n = v.shape[0]
    m = v.shape[1] 
    
    # If on the smallest grid size, compute the exact solution
    if n <= 6 or m <=6:
        v, info = jacobi_update(v, f, nsteps=1000)
        return v
    else:
        # smoothing
        v, info = jacobi_update(v, f, nsteps=10, max_err=1e-1)
        A = create_A(n, m)[0]
        
        # calculate residual
        r = np.dot(A, v.flatten()) - f.flatten()
        r = r.reshape(n,m)
        
        # downsample resitdual error
        r = restrict(r)
        zero_array = np.zeros(r.shape)
        
        # interploate the correction computed on a corser grid
        d = interpolate_array(MGV(r, zero_array))
        
        # Add prolongated corser grid solution onto the finer grid
        v = v - d
        
        v, info = jacobi_update(v, f, nsteps=10, max_err=1e-6)
        return v


sigma = 0

# Setting up the grid
k = 6
n = 2**k+2
m = 2**(k)+2

hx = 1/n
hy = 1/m

L = 1
H = 1

x = np.linspace(0, L, n)
y = np.linspace(0, H, m)
XX, YY = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Setting up the initial conditions
f = np.ones((n,m))
v = np.zeros((n,m))

# How many V cyles to perform
err = 1
n_cycles = 10
loop = True
cycle = 0

# Perform V cycles until converged or reached the maximum
# number of cycles
while loop:
    cycle += 1
    v_new = MGV(f, v)
    
    if np.abs(v - v_new).max() < err:
        loop = False
    if cycle == n_cycles:
        loop = False
    
    v = v_new

print("Number of cycles " + str(cycle))
plt.contourf(v)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65532292/how-to-iterate-over-all-elements-of-a-2d-matrix-using-only-one-loop-using-python is a recent question that tries to get rid of some double loops (which you have).  Looking at the big picture I saw that he was setting several diagonals.  To get any sort of `numpy` performance, you need to perform that kind of recoding.  I think you need to spend more time studying basic `numpy`, learning how to work with whole arrays rather than iterating over elements.

Comment: @hpaulj the vast majority of my run time is coming from line 148 which is  "vt = np.dot(Rj, vt) + np.dot(invD, f_inner)" , which is a full numpy statement. I believe this line can be optimised because Rj and invD are sparse marticies and apparently scipy has some sparse marticies dot product algorithms which may help me. I have some ways in my head to reduce the useage of for loops, but the majority of run time is not coming from the use of these for loops

Comment: What size(s) are the matrices?  You haven't use `scipy.sparse` yet, have you?  Sparsity needs to be on the order of 1% for it to help.  Sparse matrices are widely used with numerical models.  Years ago I used them to model glacial flow with finite elements in MATLAB.  With care I managed to build the stiffness matrix in about the same time it took to solve (invert) it.

Comment: If I have a grid which is n by m , then Rj and invD are (n*m)^2. For n,m = 2^7, the arrays are 99.97% empty so using scipy.sparse has massively reduced the run time of that line and can now compute 10,000 itterations of a 2^7 sized grid in ~ a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize that I'm not answering your question directly, but I do note that you have quite a few loops that will contribute some overhead cost.  When optimizing code, I have found the following thread useful - particularly the [line profiler](https://pypi.org/project/line-profiler/) thread.  This way you can focus in on "high time cost" lines and then start to ask more specific questions regarding opportunities to optimize.

[How do I get time of a Python program's execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557571/how-do-i-get-time-of-a-python-programs-execution?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: This is very useful and has helped me pin point the line with 99.5% of the run time!

Answer (score 3):

I've been writing MG algorithms for several years, here are few suggestions for improving the performance  of your code:

- Python is not ideal for CFD: It's slow, and not scalable. You really should be doing this in C or Fortran if you want the most significant performance improvements.
- Multigrid is best used not as a *solver*, but as a *preconditioner*. I would look into an algorithm like Multigrid-preconditioned conjugate gradient method for incompressible flow.
- Multigrid's performance improvements also come from its ability to be highly parallelized. Another reason to write CFD code in C or Fortran: You can use MPI or OpenMP (or both, for really big problems) to accelerate your solver significantly.
- Finally, and **most significantly**, you are using dense matrix storage! This is a big nono for most (if not all) PDE solvers. I wouldn't be surprised if most of the time spent here is done allocating the matrices. Imagine you're doing a real  3D problem with just 2^15 points per dimension. You're going to be storing a 2^15^3^2 * (8 bytes per double) array. Thats 10^32 GB of storage! If you just store the nonzeros, you're looking more at a scale of 10^6 GB, which is actually doable on modern computers. You really should look into CSR storage for your matrices, and avoid using them all together for restriction and prolongation.

I hope that gives you some starting points to improve your code.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, in the end the slowest part was the use of a dense matrix (I didnt know sparse matricies were a thing!). In the end, using scipy's sparse matrix removed the bottlekneck and it calculated 10,000 iterations of a 2^7 grid in a second (however I know that with MG the idea is that you dont need to do that many cycles because of the restriction/prolongation steps). I will look into the multigrid-preconditioned conjugate gradient method, thanks. I was trying to use the MG to solve the pressure term, but perhaps I should of used a few jacobian steps after to solve.